# easy c question: compare first char of a char array

Tags: c, arrays

How can I compare the first letter of the first element of a char**?

I have tried:

```
int main()
{
    char** command = NULL;
    while (true)
    {
        fgets(line, MAX_COMMAND_LEN, stdin);
        parse_command(line, command);
        exec_command(command);
    }
}

void parse_command(char* line, char** command)
{
    int n_args = 0, i = 0;
    while (line[i] != '\n')
    {
        if (isspace(line[i++]))
            n_args++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_args+1; i++)
        command = (char**) malloc (n_args * sizeof(char*));

    i = 0;
    line = strtok(line," \n");
    while (line != NULL)
    {
        command[i++] = (char *) malloc ( (strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(command[i++], line);
        line = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    command[i] = NULL;
}

void exec_command(char** command)
{
    if (command[0][0] == '/')
            // other stuff
}
```

but that gives a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to create foo as a list of strings?  Or just as a single string?  `*char[]` isn't sensible, did you mean `char *foo[]`?  Could you show how foo is declared?

Comment: What is the actual type you're looking for? You mean an array of strings or what? There is no such type as `*char[]`.

Comment: @nunos, if you want concrete help, you need to show us the concrete code for `//alloc and "fill" stuff`...

Comment: updated question with the code.

Comment: how is line defined? you use it immediately in `main` suggesting it is a `char[]`. But please be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you do allocate a char* array inside `parse_command`, but the pointer to that array never gets out of the function. So `exec_command` gets a garbage pointer value. The reason is, by calling `parse_command(line, command)` you pass *a copy of the current value* of the pointer `command`, which is then overwritten inside the function - but *the original value is not affected by this!*

To achieve that, either you need to pass *a pointer to* the pointer you want to update, or you need to return the pointer to the allocated array from `parse_command`. Apart from `char***` looking ugly (at least to me), the latter approach is simpler and easier to read:

```
int main()
{
    char** command = NULL;
    while (true)
    {
        fgets(line, MAX_COMMAND_LEN, stdin);
        command = parse_command(line);
        exec_command(command);
    }
}

char** parse_command(char* line)
{
    char** command = NULL;
    int n_args = 0, i = 0;
    while (line[i] != '\n')
    {
        if (isspace(line[i++]))
            n_args++;
    }

    command = (char**) malloc ((n_args + 1) * sizeof(char*));

    i = 0;
    line = strtok(line," \n");
    while (line != NULL)
    {
        command[i] = (char *) malloc ( (strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(command[i++], line);
        line = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    command[i] = NULL;
    return command;
}
```

Notes:

- in your original `parse_command`, you allocate memory to `command` in a loop, which is unnecessary and just creates memory leaks. It is enough to allocate memory once. I assume that you want `command` to contain `n_args + 1` pointers, so I modified the code accordingly.
- in the last `while` loop of `parse_command`, you increment `i` incorrectly twice, which also leads to undefined behaviour, i.e. possible segmentation fault. I fixed it here.

Answer (score 2):

Could you paste more code?  Have you allocated memory both for your char* array and for the elements of your char* array?